# Manga where a guy has a vision-related power that he uses to gamble

Tags: story-identification, manga

The guy has a power in his eyes. He had it since he was born. He learns how to use his power. After learning it he used his eyes on gambling. He can see the winning numbers on the roulette. After all that fame he got, the power slowly fades away. When the power in his eyes is totally gone, he becomes a man with a lot of debts. Even his family disowned him. He goes to his girlfriend to ask for money, she got angry and said she wanted to break up and that was the last money that she would give to the guy. I think the girl works in a restaurant or a coffee shop or something I cant remember.

The guy leaves the shop after he received the money through mobile. The guy then started walking thinking deeply about his misfortune. He eventually ended in a park where a mysterious woman contractor appeared and offered to give the guy a chance to redeem himself and pay all of his debt. The guy was thinking if he will accept it or not. In the end, he accepted the offer. But not under a total contract but an invitation. He was then given a special seal coming from the contractor. I think those seals were given to the contractors by their gods. I don't know what these seals can do.

The guy texted his girlfriend so they can meet up and apologize. Then the guy waited for his girlfriend to come but he was already transported to another world. When the girl arrived to meet him, her ex-bf was gone and she only saw a used cigarette on the floor. She had no idea where the guy went or what happened.

Comment: Its a manga. I cant remember the story i just read a few chapters of it way back, because its still updating.. But i remembered one of his eyes has power. And it uses a mobile phone to go back n forth to the another world

Comment: I think he has the power on his eye since he was born. The power is gone because he overused it for nothing he uses his eye for gambling. Lots of loses when his power is gone he cant see the the winning numbers on the roulette. Umh not offer. His girlfriend gave him money out of his consent. Maybe he loved the guy so she will give money.  Yes he accepted the offer to go to another.  What i remembered when he was going to apologise to her gf he was transported to the another world. When the girl showed up he didnt see his bf bec he was transported.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like *The Second Coming of Gluttony*.

> Synopsis: Seol Jihu, also known as just Seol, is the main protagonist
> of The Second Coming of Gluttony.
>
> At the start of the story, Seol is a gambling addict, deep in debt and
> scorned by his family and ex-girlfriend. However, due to an
> opportunity granted to him by his past life, he obtained a second
> chance to set things right.
>
> He possesses the unique innate ability, Nine Eyes, which inadvertently
> caused his gambling addiction after its disappearance as a result of
> over-abusing the ability. However, experiencing a lucid dream about
> his past life, it once again reawakened, becoming a powerful ally on
> his long journey to redemption.
>
> [Source](https://the-second-coming-of-gluttony.fandom.com/wiki/Seol_Jihu)

I haven't read the novel, but in the Manhwa, he can see the things he has to bet in a green light. In the beginning of the history, he goes to his ex-girlfriend to ask for money.

After he recovers his ability, he goes to this new world.

The story you talk about a compass is Second Life Ranker.

Comment: Let me check. But i think youre right..